# Is there a better way with NodeJs to get updates from a Telegram bot?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using simply like below:

```
class Bot {
   constructor(token) {
     let _baseApiURL = `https://api.telegram.org`;
     //code here
   }

   getAPI(apiName) {
    return axios.get(`${this.getApiURL()}/${apiName}`);
   }

   getApiURL() {
     return `${this.getBaseApiUrl()}/bot${this.getToken()}`;
   }

   getUpdates(fn) {
        this.getAPI('getUpdates')
            .then(res => {
                this.storeUpdates(res.data);
                fn(res.data);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.getUpdates(fn);
                }, 1000);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('::: ERROR :::', err);
            });
    }
}
const bot = new Bot('mytoken');
bot.start();
```

I'd like to know whether there is a better way to listen for Telegram's updates, instead of using a timeout and redo an Ajax call to 'getUpdates' API

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: Yes, I've already read the documentation thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram supports polling or webhooks, so you can use the latter to avoid polling the `getUpdates` API

### Getting updates

> There are two mutually exclusive ways of receiving updates for your
>   bot — the getUpdates method on one hand and Webhooks on the other.
>   Incoming updates are stored on the server until the bot receives them
>   either way, but they will not be kept longer than 24 hours.

Regardless of which option you choose, you will receive JSON-serialized Update objects as a result.

More info on: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates

---

You can use [telegraf](http://%20https://telegraf.js.org/) to easily setup a [webhook](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=webhooks) or to handle the polling for you with a great API