# Node class start function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to javascript/node and I am building a class that calls the Telegram api every second to get updates and store so I can have other function use that data. I have pieced together code form examples but I am getting an error when I call `bot.start();` because no function is being passed to `getUpdates`. I am not sure why the `(fn)` is needed.

```
class Bot {
    constructor(token) {
      let _baseApiURL = `https://api.telegram.org`;
      this.baseApiURL = _baseApiURL;
      this.token = token;
    }

    start(){
        this.getUpdates();
    }

    getBaseApiUrl(){
        return this.baseApiURL;
    }

    getToken(){
        return this.token;
    }

    getAPI(apiName) {
     return axios.get(`${this.getApiURL()}/${apiName}`);
    }

    getApiURL() {
      return `https://api.telegram.org/bot${this.getToken()}`;
    }

    getUpdates(fn) {
         this.getAPI('getUpdates')
             .then(res => {
                 this.storeUpdates(res.data);
                 fn(res.data);
                 setTimeout(() => {
                     this.getUpdates(fn);
                 }, 1000);
             })
             .catch(err => {
                 console.log('::: ERROR :::', err);
             });
     }

     storeUpdates(data){
        console.log(data);
     }
 }
 const bot = new Bot(TOKEN);
 bot.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve with that `fn` method. You are not passing any method, therefore it fails. This would work

```
getUpdates() {
     this.getAPI('getUpdates')
         .then(res => {
             this.storeUpdates(res.data);
             setTimeout(() => {
                 this.getUpdates();
             }, 1000);
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log('::: ERROR :::', err);
         });
 }
```

If you want to implement some kind of Observer pattern, you should not couple it with `getUpdates` method, just create methods for registering observers and notify them when store is changed.

Also the way how you trigger the repetition is not too good, because once you get error (and with HTTP methods you usually get some ERROR sooner or later) it will break the whole flow.
Use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron to trigger periodic actions.

Comment: thanks, I was building upon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275931/is-there-a-better-way-with-nodejs-to-get-updates-from-a-telegram-bot and I am not sure myself what use was the `fn`